# Cross-browser solution for printing a PDF that's encoded as a data URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, printing

On Firefox, `const printWindow = window.open(pdfDataUrl)` opens a new window with the PDF loaded and ready to print. However following it with `printWindow.print()` fails to wait long enough for the PDF to be ready before printing, and `printWindow.onload = printWindow.print` never fires for some reason.

On Chrome, `const printWindow = window.open(pdfDataUrl)` doesn't work. Answers to other Stack Overflow questions recommend wrapping the data URL in an iframe. That works, but then calling `iframeElement.contentWindow.print()` does nothing. As a potential workaround, the user can right-click on the frame contents and click print.

Is there a cross-browser solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

[PrintJS](https://printjs.crabbly.com/) should work. It is a library for printing in html. Try using:

```js
PrintJS({printable: /*Add dataURL here*/, type: 'pdf', base64: true})
```

After adding `<script src='https://printjs-4de6.kxcdn.com/print.min.js'></script>` to your HTML.